# Laravel 5 and Angular 2 Authorization

Tags: laravel, angular, access-levels

I used Laravel 5.3 as the back-end language and angular 2 as front-en. 
My question is when the user logged into system how determine current user access list and how angular detects that the user can't access current route or specific section of dom.

Comment: Tell us what you have tried so far.

Comment: JWT Auth Token will be your saving grace here.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy  can you show me an example?

Comment: Since you are using Angular 2, I presume you must be having APIs to connect to your Laravel App, which you can authenticate using Laravel API authentication using Passport, read more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport), where you can have tokens to validate API requests